# Problema con el Timer y TimerTask Java

Tags: java, timer

estoy creando un Timer y un TimerTask pero estoy teniendo problemas ya que solo necesito que se ejecute cuando unda espacio hasta ahi voy bien, el problema es que necesito que el se repita hasta que yo use el cancel(). Estoy haciendo un proyecto para la universidad por tal razón no puedo liberar todo el código pero pues espero que me puedan ayudar con lo que ponga, muchas gracias de ante mano. El solo entra una vez y no se sigue ejecutando, ¿cómo puedo solucionar eso?

```
moverseBola = new Timer();
        tareaMoverBola = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                jugar();
            }

        };
        moverseBola.schedule(tareaMoverBola, 0);

public void moverBarras(int i) {
        if (i == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
            if (nave.hayBola() != null) {
                nave.ajustarBola(null);
            } else if (numJugadores == 2 && naveDos.hayBola() != null) {
                naveDos.ajustarBola(null);
            }
            tareaMoverBola.run();
        } else if (i == KeyEvent.VK_P) {
            tareaMoverBola.cancel();

        }
        if (numJugadores == 1) {
            nave.moverBarra(i);
        }else if (numJugadores == 2) {
            nave.moverBarra(i);
            naveDos.moverBarra(i);
            hayChoqueEntreNaves();

        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

El Timer sirve para programar tareas, pero no veo que estés programando tareas mas que una vez, e inmediatamente, aquí:

```
    moverseBola.schedule(tareaMoverBola, 0);
```

Luego estás invocando el método run() de una tarea. No entiendo porque, pero sería válido.

Quieres cancelar la tarea con este método:

```
        tareaMoverBola.cancel();
```

Este método no cancela el proceso de jugar(), ese método lo que cancela es la tarea dentro del Timer, pero por lo que veo solo programas la tarea una vez.

Creo que necesitas cambiar la forma en que cancelas el juego teniendo un método:

```
 cancelaJuegar();
```

Y sustituir tareaMoverBola.cancel(), que estás cancelando la programación de esa tarea, por cancelaJugar(), que sería el método que cancela el que se siga jugando.